# How to store object of different class types into one container in modern c++?

Tags: c++

I ran into this problem, where I want to store different classes (sharing same interface) into a common container.

Is it posssible to do that in modern C++?

Is this allowed, when I don't want to store objects as pointers? If I have to use pointer, then what should be the recommended or cleaner way to do that?

What should be the correct approach to handle such usecases?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

enum class TYPES: int {TYPE1 = 0, TYPE2, INVALID};

class IObj
{
public:
    virtual auto ObjType(void) -> TYPES = 0;
};

class InterfaceObj: IObj
{
public:
    virtual auto Printable(void) -> void = 0;
};

class InterfaceTesla
{
public:
    virtual auto Creatable(void) -> void = 0;
};

class CObj: InterfaceObj
{
private:
    std::string msg;
public:
    CObj()
    {
        msg = "Elon Mask!";
    }
    virtual auto ObjType(void) -> TYPES override
    {
        return TYPES::TYPE1;
    }
    virtual auto Printable(void) -> void override
    {
        std::cout<<msg<<std::endl;
    }
};

class CObjTesla: public CObj, InterfaceTesla
{
private:
    std::string vhc;
public:
    CObjTesla()
    : CObj()
    {
        vhc = "Cybertruck";
    }
    virtual auto ObjType(void) -> TYPES override
    {
        return TYPES::TYPE2;
    }
    virtual auto Creatable(void) -> void override
    {
        std::cout<<vhc<<" was launched by ";
        Printable();
    }
};


int main()
{
    std::vector<CObj> vec; // How am I supposed to declare this container?

    for(auto i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        CObjTesla obj1;
        CObj obj2;
        vec.push_back(static_cast<CObj>(obj1)); // what should be the correct type of the container?
        vec.push_back((obj2));
    }

    for(auto &iter : vec)
    {
        switch(iter.ObjType())
        {
            case TYPES::TYPE1: 
                iter.Printable();
            break;
            case TYPES::TYPE2: 
                auto temp = const_cast<CObjTesla>(iter); //?? what shoud I do here?
                temp.Creatable();
            break;
            case TYPES::INVALID:
            default:
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to avoid using pointers?

Comment: It cannot be done without pointers. Storing an instance into the container which has base class as element type, you will get [object slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/274634/7478597) (i.e. only the base class part of instance is copied into container).

Comment: @StephenNewell just that sometime pointers are very difficult to handle the life spans.

Comment: Have you taken a look at `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr`?

Comment: @StephenNewell yes. I use them, but don't have a comprehensive plan on how to  work with smart pointers in this problem. what should be the a clean solution, even if it has to be with smart pointers.

Comment: It looks like you're using a tagged union and want `std::variant`, which can be handled with `std::visit` without virtual interfaces. `std::unique_ptr` is the way to go in the other direction.

Comment: I added a smart pointer example to my answer... if you need further help, feel free to ask!

Comment: @kishoredbn write modern does not imply write ugly. What's the point of all of those `void` input parameters and and `auto` return type for simple types?

Comment: @moia I think `auto` for return is just a cleaner way to make codes more readable(obviously, that is not the functional use of `auto` in return type). Just the 4-letter word in front of function name lays function names in fixed indentation making it more readable especially when you're looking at codes in a colorless text-editor. `void` input parameter is an industry-wide recommendation for programming in `c`, for days when you are actually mixing `c` and `.cpp`. [link](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/286490/what-is-the-difference-between-function-and-functionvoid)

Comment: @kishoredbn you have a point so.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can store different object types in a `std::variant`. If you do so, there is no need to have a common interface and use virtual functions.

Example:

```
class A
{
    public:
        void DoSomething() { std::cout << "DoSomething from A" << std::endl; }
};

class B
{
    public:
        void DoSomething() { std::cout << "DoSomething from B" << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector< std::variant< A, B > > objects;

    objects.push_back( A{} );
    objects.push_back( B{} );

    for ( auto& obj: objects )
    {
        std::visit( [](auto& object ){ object.DoSomething(); }, obj);
    }
}
```

But using this solutions *can* have also drawbacks. Access via `std::visit` *may* be slow. Sometimes e.g. gcc generates very bad code in such situations. ( jump table is generated in runtime, no idea why! ). You always call the function via table access which takes some additional time. And storing the objects in `std::variant` consumes always the size of the biggest class you have in the variant and in addition you need some space for the tag variable inside the variant.

The "old" way is to store raw or better smart-pointers into the vector and simply call via base pointer the common interface functions. The drawback here is the additional vtable pointer in each instance ( which is typically the same size as the tag variable in the std::variant ). The indirection with vtable access to call the function comes also with a ( small ) cost.

Example with smart pointer of base type and vector:

```
class Interface
{
    public:
        virtual void DoSomething() = 0;
        virtual ~Interface() = default;
};

class A: public Interface
{
    public:
        void DoSomething() override { std::cout << "DoSomething from A" << std::endl; }
        virtual ~A(){ std::cout << "Destructor called for A" << std::endl; }
};

class B: public Interface
{
    public:
        void DoSomething() override { std::cout << "DoSomething from B" << std::endl; }
        virtual ~B(){ std::cout << "Destructor called for B" << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector< std::shared_ptr<Interface>> pointers;

    pointers.emplace_back( std::make_shared<A>() );
    pointers.emplace_back( std::make_shared<B>() );

    for ( auto& ptr: pointers )
    {
        ptr->DoSomething();
    }
}
```

If `std::unique_ptr` is sufficient for you, you can use that one. It depends on the need of passing pointers around or not in your design.

Hint: If you are using pointers to base class type never forget to make your destructors virtual! See also: [When to use virtual destructors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461203/when-to-use-virtual-destructors)

In your case I would vote to use smart-pointers of base class type in simple vector!

BTW:

```
virtual auto ObjType(void) -> TYPES
```

That look ugly to me! No need for `auto` here as the return type is known before you write the function parameter list. In such cases, where template parameters are need to be deduced to define the return type, it is needed, but not here! Please do not use always auto!

Comment: Thanks for sharing your thoughts. I am accepting your answer. BTW.. there is no functional use of `auto` as I'm using the code. All I'm trying to do here is make the all the function declaration look consistent for better readability.

Comment: @kishoredbn: As Moia also remarked, we have a different opinion about readability. :-) But yes, it is a matter of taste...

Comment: I think when too many people said so, then I think I should reconsider this choice of code formatting.

Answer (score 4):

### std::unique_ptr

The most common way to hold polymorphic types inside a vector is by using ***std::unique_ptr***:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base>> vec;
vec.push_back(std::make_unique<Derived1>(/*Derived1 params*/));
vec.push_back(std::make_unique<Derived2>(/*Derived2 params*/));
```

> It sounds that you are not happy with this solution as you want to "hide" any use of pointers.

### std::reference_wrapper

This is usually not helpful, but in case you need to hold reference to object that you KNOW would outlive the lifetime of the vector, you can use ***std::reference_wrapper***:

```
Derived1 d1; // outlives the vector
Derived2 d2; // outlives the vector
// ...
// some inner scope or down the stack
    std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<Base>> vec;
    vec.push_back(d1);
    vec.push_back(d2);
```

> This option is not relevant in your case, as the objects that are passed into the vector are local, so they must be copied to and managed by the vector.

### Your own *Holder* Proxy class

In some cases it is reasonable to create your own *Holder* class that would conceal the use of pointers or even conceal the use of polymorphism.

This can be achieved in your case like this:

```
class CObjHolder {
    std::unique_ptr<CObj> pobj;
public:
    template<typename T>
    CObjHolder(const T& obj) {
        pobj = std::make_unique<T>(obj);
    }
    const CObj& operator*() const {
        return *pobj;
    }
    CObj& operator*() {
        return *pobj;
    }
    const CObj* operator->() const {
        return pobj.get();
    }
    CObj* operator->() {
        return pobj.get();
    }
};
```

With your own *Holder* class you can simply use a vector of *Holder* objects:

```
std::vector<CObjHolder> vec;
```

Adding to the vector would be easy:

```
for(auto i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    CObjTesla obj1;
    CObj obj2;
    vec.push_back(obj1);
    vec.push_back(obj2);
}
```

To use the objects you would go through `operator->` of the *Holder*:

```
for(const auto& item : vec)
{
    switch(item->ObjType())
    {
        case OBJ_TYPE::TYPE1: 
            item->Print();
        break;
        case OBJ_TYPE::TYPE2: 
            static_cast<const CObjTesla&>(*item).DoSomething();
            // doable, though better if can avoid checking types
            // and rely more on dynamic or static polymorphism
        break;
        case OBJ_TYPE::INVALID:
        default:
            // error log
        break;
    }
}
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2ce9f2246160b95f

One may argue that the use of *Holder* class is redundant. However the idea of hiding your polymorphic type may have its advantages. The *Holder* class is serving as a [Proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern) to the actual implementation.

The proxy may implement some of the functionality that is relevant for the usage of the types that it represents. For example in this case the switch that appears in main may move into the proxy which may then discard the need of direct access of the actual object it holds:

```
class CObjHolder {
    std::unique_ptr<CObj> pobj;
public:
    template<typename T>
    CObjHolder(const T& obj) {
        pobj = std::make_unique<T>(obj);
    }
    void DoYourThing() const {
        switch(pobj->ObjType())
        {
            case OBJ_TYPE::TYPE1: 
                pobj->Print();
            break;
            case OBJ_TYPE::TYPE2: 
                std::cout << "@@@" << std::endl;
                static_cast<const CObjTesla&>(*pobj).DoSomething();
            break;
            case OBJ_TYPE::INVALID:
            default:
                // error log
            break;
        }
    }
};
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e8266e0a356d825a

Comment: What is your "holder" made for? It is half of a smart pointer but isn't smart, especially because it did not deal with lifetime of the object. And what I see is very curious: Having a virtual function to get the "object type id" and do a handcrafted switch case. That will have all drawbacks you can have: Need of vtable AND a tag and in addition also a handcrafted switch case. All this can be achieved by using a variant more easily. Isn't it?

Comment: @Klaus well it does deal with the lifetime of the object by holding a unique_ptr. If your question is why to wrap a unique_ptr inside a class that doesn't add much to it, then the answer is inside my post: sometimes there is a wish to "hide" the use of a pointer or even to hide the polymorphism from the user. It might be what the OP was looking for. The added value of the Holder class in this case is mainly its constructor which allows very simple call to push_back. The idea of Holder can be used to add other functionalities (e.g. move the switch on type into Holder).

Comment: I can't see any benefit of wrapping a smart pointer into another "holder". And handcrafted switch case with casting and getting the type id via a virtual function is a bad solution in my eyes. If you simply use std::variant< std::unqiue_ptr<A>, std::unqiue_ptr<b>> you get a much cleaner, faster, easier to maintain and less error prone solution. It seems that the problem starts with the "wish" to hide a pointer. But ending up in modified class with an additional virtual interface to make it useable in the handcrafted stuff around.  Sorry, but it has so many "bad" things...

Comment: In my experience Holder as a Proxy is useful, especially as additional requirements arise. This leaves the option of easy refactoring (e.g. replacing switch with a visitor) as the actual logic of handling the polymorphic hierarchy is encapsulated. The possibility of merely using unique_ptr is of course still relevant and mentioned in my answer (good to see you added this option also to yours).